# How to slice continuous and discontinuous index in pandas?

Tags: pandas

`pandas` `iloc` could slice dataframe two cases such as `df.iloc[:,2:5]` and `df.iloc[:,[6,10]]`.
If I want to select `2:5, 6 and 10` columns, how to use  `iloc` to slice `df`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [numpy.r_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

From docs:

> Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.
>
> This is a simple way to build up arrays quickly. There are two use
> cases.
>
> If the index expression contains comma separated arrays, then stack
> them along their first axis.
>
> If the index expression contains slice
> notation or scalars then create a 1-D array with a range indicated by
> the slice notation.

Demo:

```
In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 12))

In [17]: df.iloc[:, np.r_[2:5, 6, 10]]
Out[17]:
         2         3         4         6         10
0  0.760201  0.378125  0.707002  0.310077  0.375646
1  0.770165  0.269465  0.419979  0.218768  0.832087
2  0.253142  0.737015  0.652522  0.474779  0.094145

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        11
0  0.668062  0.581268  0.760201  0.378125  0.707002  0.249094  0.310077  0.336708  0.847258  0.705631  0.375646  0.830852
1  0.521096  0.798405  0.770165  0.269465  0.419979  0.455890  0.218768  0.833776  0.862483  0.817974  0.832087  0.958174
2  0.211815  0.747482  0.253142  0.737015  0.652522  0.274231  0.474779  0.256119  0.110760  0.224096  0.094145  0.525201
```

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

So I updated my answer in order to fix that deprecated feature: changed `.ix[]` --> `df.iloc[...]`

Comment: So fast! THx Both of you !

Comment: Glad we can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate indices and then [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting by positions:

```
ds = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3],
                   'G':[1,3,5],
                   'H':[5,3,6],
                   'I':[4,4,3],
                   'J':[6,4,3],
                   'K':[9,4,3]})

print (ds)
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K
0  1  4  7  1  5  7  1  5  4  6  9
1  2  5  8  3  3  4  3  3  4  4  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3  5  6  3  3  3

print (np.r_[2:5, 6,10])
[ 2  3  4  6 10]

print (ds.iloc[:, np.r_[2:5, 6,10]])
   C  D  E  G  K
0  7  1  5  1  9
1  8  3  3  3  4
2  9  5  6  5  3
```

To discussion:

`ix` vs `iloc` - main problem is `ix` [will be deprecated in Pandas 0.20.0](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix). And [it seems](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html) new version is soon - in April, so better is use `iloc`.